# mysql left join max value on all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

I have the following table:

Table Scores:

```
+----+-------+
| Id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |   300 |
|  2 |   300 |
|  3 |   300 |
|  4 |   100 |
|  5 |   200 |
+----+-------+
```

What I need as a result of the query:

```
+----+-------+
| Id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |   300 |
|  2 |   300 |
|  3 |   300 |
|  4 |   300 |
|  5 |   300 |
+----+-------+
```

With what query can I achieve this?

(this is just part of a complex query, this would help a lot to minimize my code)

Comment: `SELECT id, (SELECT MAX(value) FROM mytable) FROM mytable`

Comment: `select id, max from scores left join (select max(value) as max from scores) as maxval`?

Comment: @MarcB I think you mean `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: It's a shame this has to be done in MySQL.  Pretty much every other popular SQL database supports window functions, which would be the ideal way to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `cross join` the table with a query that returns the max value:

```
SELECT     id, max_value
FROM       scores
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(value) AS max_value 
            FROM scores) m
```